# Не получается передать значение из активности в фрагмент?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, activity, android-bundle

Из главной активности вызываю фрагмент

```
<fragment class="com.example.viktor.buyersguide.Section"
```

В этом фрагменте составляется список и дальше передается выбранное значение пользователем

```
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        if (listenerSection != null) listenerSection.itemClicked(id);
    }
```

А в главной активности в методе  `public void itemClicked(long id)` (поскольку я реализую `implements Section.ListSection`) создается интент

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Main2Activity.SUB_SECTION_ID, (int)id);
    startActivity(intent);
```

И передаетя выбранный `id`. В разметке открывшейся новой активности `Main2Activity`,также вызывается новый фрагмент со списком

```
 <fragment class="com.example.viktor.buyersguide.SubSection"
```

И мне нужно передать из этой активности (`Main2Activity`) `id` в фрагмент `SubSection`. Я это пробую через `Bundle`:

```
int cardsId = (int) getIntent().getExtras().get(SUB_SECTION_ID);
        Bundle subSectionId = new Bundle();
        subSectionId.putInt("idSub", cardsId);

        SubSection subSection = new SubSection();
        subSection.setArguments(subSectionId);
```

А в `SubSection` вынимаю

```
Bundle subSectionId = this.getArguments();
        if (subSectionId != null) {
            this.id = subSectionId.getInt("idSub");
        }
```

, заранее создав переменную `int id;`. 
Однако, она всегда "0". В чем может быть проблема или как иначе можно передать значение?

Comment: Скорее всего код, где вы достаете id выполняется быстрее чем передача из активити во фрагмент id. Где вы выполняете этот код?

Comment: ну вот где первый фрагмент загружается (от первой активности) и там id передается в главную активность из фрагмента. Затем из этой уже активности через интент второй активности и из второй активности во второй фрагмент, где id уже 0

Comment: проблема в интенте, то бишь во второй активности когда я принимаю значение из интента, оно уже NullPointer

Comment: вопрос почему..

Answer (score 2):

У вас фрагмент добавлен в активити через разметку. Это не самое лучшее решение. Лучше добавлять фрагменты программно.

Также вы неправильно передаёте аргументы во фрагмент. Надо не в новый экземпляр оного передавать, а в тот, который вы на экране отображаете.

Однако вы не можете передать аргументы корректно во фрагмент, добавленный в разметке. Так что вам нужно добавить его программно и при создании экземпляра фрагмента передать в него аргументы. Тогда у всё всё будет работать.